# Proof that < is a linear order

Tags: induction, set-theory, order-theory

I am reading the book *Introduction to Set Theory* by Thomas & Karel, 3rd edition.

And I am stuck on the proof of Theorem 2.2 in chapter 3 about natural numbers. Specifically, part iii of the proof. It says that: $\lt$ is a linear order of $\Bbb N$ (where $\lt$ is the strict ordering on $\Bbb N$).

The proof proceeds by induction on $n$ for the statement

> $\forall m,n \in \Bbb N$ either $m \lt n$ or $m=n$ or $n \lt m$.

The case $0$ is simple.

Then the induction step supposes that:

> $\forall m,n \in \Bbb N$ either $m \lt n$ or $m=n$ or $n \lt m$

Here the authors go step by step for each part, namely they prove that $m \lt n+1$ then $m=n+1$ then the third part with which I have a problem of understanding. Namely they say, and I quote

> Finally, if $n \lt m$, we would like to conclude that $n+1 \leq m$. This would show that for all $m,n \in \Bbb N$, either $m \lt n+1$ or $m= n+1$ or $n+1 \lt m$

And then they go by induction again on $m$ to prove that

> if $n \lt m$, we would like to conclude that $n+1 \leq m$.

The thing I am not getting is why "we would like to conclude that $n+1 \leq m$."  I would expect to aim for "we would like to conclude that $n+1 \lt m$" which concludes the main induction step. I.e I don't see why he used $\leq$ instead of $\lt$, or why does this work for proving the main induction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because if $2 < 3$ then $2+1 \le 3$ and not $2+1 < 3$

Comment: Is the definition of *less than* that $a < b \iff (a - b) < 0 \iff (b - a) > 0 \iff (b > a)$?